# How to deploy a activiti bpm workflow at run time using java?

Tags: java, activiti, business-process-management

I am getting error when i try to deploy a work flow at run time.
Following java code used to deploy my work flow

```
ProcessEngine processEngine=ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration().buildProcessEngine();

    RepositoryService repositoryService=processEngine.getRepositoryService();
    repositoryService.createDeployment().addClasspathResource("resources/diagrams/MyProcess.bpmn").deploy();


    RuntimeService runtimeService=processEngine.getRuntimeService();
    ProcessInstance processInstance=runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("myProcess");
```

Any suggestion to deploy work flow dynamically ? thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the error?  What's the process BPMN look like?

Comment: Thank u  matts..I have two sample work flow. Manually i deployed first work flow(through activiti-explorer UI).This flow has a service task with its service class.Now i want deploy my second work from inside of  this service class .

Comment: public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("First Work flow deployed");
  ProcessEngine processEngine=ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration().buildProcessEngine();  
  RepositoryService repositoryService=processEngine.getRepositoryService();
  repositoryService.createDeployment().addClasspathResource("resources/diagrams/sample2.bpmn").deploy();  
  RuntimeService runtimeService=processEngine.getRuntimeService();
  ProcessInstance processInstance=runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById("sample2");  
  }

Comment: Exceptions :-org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't create db schema: cre
ate table ACT_HI_PROCINST (

Comment: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ACT_HI_PROCINST" already exists;
 SQL statement:

Comment: Hello everyone, do you know how we can add the extension properties to a deployment for activiti 7.3.0 ?